# Getting confused by 'initial-scale=1.0'

Tags: html, mobile, viewport, meta

In most modern webpages, the following piece of code is used to make the webpage more managable in a mobile device:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I am slightly confused by the following though:

```
"initial-scale=1.0"
```

Can i just use the following?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                                     //instead of: initial-scale=1.0
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: It is just a percentage so 1.0 or 1 equals to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

That's even [the example used on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_basics).